# Некорректное отображение PDF файла при рисовании через Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, render, uikit

Столкнулся с проблемой некорректного отображения некоторых PDF файлов при рисовании через Core Graphics Context. Фоновые блоки рисуются корректно, а текст не отображается.

[image: Wrong rendering example]

Беглый анализ PDF файла он-лайн инструментами показал, что все тексты сохранены отдельными картинками с каким-то странным разрешением и dpi. При этом с логотипом все в порядке.

[image: Analysis pdf]

Общая схема рисования pdf следующая:

```
    // #1 Load CGPDFDocument from file
    guard let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path)) else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
        // #2 Enumerate a file pages
        for pageNumber in 1...pdf.numberOfPages {
            guard let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: pageNumber) else { return }

            var pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
            // #3 Rendering current page
            var previewImage: UIImage?
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
                previewImage = renderer.image { ctx in
                    // ...
                    // #4 Draw PDF page on the context
                    ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
```

Проблема стабильно повторяется на iPhone X (iOS 11) и iPhone 8 (iOS 11). На других устройствах (в т.ч. с ш) все ок.

Файл конвертируется из pptx презентации через Microsoft Powerpoint. Разумеется, если файл сконвертировать в pdf через, например Keynote, то все отображается корректно, текст сохранен текстом, а не картинками.

Также из интересных особенностей при просмотре в приложениях Files и Books pdf выглядит корректно, а в системном превью при печати на принтере некорректно.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей подскажите, куда копать? 
И есть ли какие-то альтернативные способы рисования pdf из файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копнул глубже. Как оказалось все достаточно просто решается.

В iOS 11 Apple добавила [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) для простой и удобной работы с этим форматом. Код получения UIImage из страниц PDF файла, в моем приложении, выглядит теперь следующим образом:

```
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // iOS 11 approach
    // #1 Load PDFDocument using PDFKit
    if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: fileURL) {
       // #2 Enumerate a file pages
        while pdfDocument.pageCount > index {
            guard let pdfPage = pdfDocument.page(at: index) else { continue }
            // #3 Rendering current pages thimbnail 
            pageImages.append(pdfPage.thumbnail(of: self.canvasSize, for: .mediaBox))
            index += 1
        }
    }
} else {
    // iOS 10 and earlier
    // #1 Load CGPDFDocument from file
    guard let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path)) else { return }

    // #2 Enumerate a file pages
    for pageNumber in 1...pdf.numberOfPages {
        guard let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: pageNumber) else { return }

        var pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        // #3 Rendering current page
        var previewImage: UIImage?
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
            previewImage = renderer.image { ctx in
                // ...
                // #4 Draw PDF page on the context
                ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)
            }
        }
        guard let preview = previewImage else { return }
        pageImages.append(preview)
    }
```

Не забудте добавить `import PDFKit`.